# source syntax error

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, anaconda

I am trying to use an anaconda virtualenv, which gets created successfully but I cannot source it. When I run `source activate myenv` I end up getting syntax errors:

```
bash: activate: line 39: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: activate: line 39: `}'
```

I obviously did't touch the `activate` script, and I have the feeling it has nothing to do with anaconda: I just noticed that I get a syntax error when trying to `source .bashrc` too:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 184: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Opening new terminals doesn't give any errors, meaning that there isn't actually an error in my .bashrc.

Doing a bit of research, I found people having issues with file encodings, e.g. moving files from Windows to linux, but it's not my case. I didn't do any such thing and I already tried converting the formats to unix.

Did I break the `source` command? But how..? Any cues on how ti fix it? Thanks!

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and (if it means anything), anaconda3 4.4.7

Comment: Where did you get Anaconda v4.4.7? The [repo](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) only has v4.4.0. Did you try a current version? Did you report that to their [bugtracker](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues)?

Comment: I downloaded anaconda directly from its website. I haven't tried the repo version yet, I might as well give it a try

Comment: Their (semi-) [current issues](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22syntax+error+near%22) look promising that this could be fixed in a newer version (resp. w/ a less exotic prompt).